# How to handle multiple session tranaction commit and rollback in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have one question  in my code I am using server and client session obj. like this

```
Session serverSession=HibernateUtilServer.getSession();
Session clientSession=HibernateUtilLocal.getSession();
```

// some database  operation here ....

```
serverSession.beginTransaction().commit();
clientSession.beginTransaction().commit();
```

But problem is that `serverSession.beginTransaction().commit();` **after this line if I am getting some network issue means some exception**. I cant commit my clientSession data this is ok means I can `clientSession.beginTransaction().rollBack();`. So I want to rollBack serverSession data also how to do this please help me..

**Note: Here serverSession and clientSession both have different database connection and different configurations file**
thank you..

Answer (score 2):

The session-per-request pattern uses one JDBC connection per session if you run local transactions. For JTA, the connections are aggressively released after each statement only to be reacquired for the next statement.

The Hibernate transaction API delegates the begin/commit/rollback to the JDBC Connection for local transactions and to the associated UserTransaction for JTA. Therefore, you can run multiple transactions on the same Hibernate Session, but there's a catch. Once an exception is thrown you can no longer reuse that Session.

My advice is to divide-and-conquer. Just split all items, construct a Command object for each of those and send them to an ExecutorService#invokeAll. Use the returned List to iterate and call Future#get() to make sure the original thread waits after all batch jobs to complete.

The ExecutorService will make sure you run all Commands concurrently and each Command should use a Service that uses its own @Transaction. Because transactions are thread-bound you will have all batch jobs run in isolation.

Comment: You could have added the source of the comment.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on use of hibernate & spring. I see that you used very good framework . it has already very good transaction management support. I suggest you that don't do this things manually. use its core transaction support. Just example: 
@Transaction Annotation which you marked at method level, class level etc Just read how it works!!. you will get better idea.

Refer link : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

**EDIT**
If you are not using spring then you need to catch exception. And you need to rollback transaction there. if you want to add framework layer then add supper class or common method to rollback transaction. call into catch block.

Comment: thank you for reply.
 But I am not using spring framework